# How to use Redis within a C++ program?

Tags: c++, database, redis

What would be the best way to use a Redis DB within a C++ program?

Comment: just use hiredis (C), it'll works fine..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a [C bindings](http://code.google.com/p/credis/) library? There doesn't seem to be a C++ wrapper available anywhere.

Comment: A caveat is that the project page says it's alpha, and not all commands are supported.

Comment: Well, it's open source, so you can always contribute :)

Comment: I think this is out of date. That is not the recommended C API and there are several C++ APIs (http://redis.io/clients#c--) as mentioned by feuGene.

Answer (score 15):

I have forked the fictorial redis-cplusplus-client, made it compatible to redis-server v2.0, added missing api calls and implemented consistent hashing. 
There is also an early state of high level classes that will be useable like stl types in the near future (shared_string, shared_int, shared_set, ...). Nothing is production ready yet but the provided tests are succesfully running :-)

http://github.com/mrpi/redis-cplusplus-client

Comment: depends on the boost library unfortunately. Already voted but if I could I'd take it back. Boost is a heavy dependency for lightweight projects.

Answer (score 8):

**Official list of C++ clients**

Explore a **full list** of [Redis C++ clients on redis.io](http://redis.io/clients#c--). You will find there different clients based on boost, Qt, etc. Note that at this time none of the C++ client implementations are marked as "Recommended."  But there is a recommended C client, [hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis), which should work just fine in C++.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/brianwatling/redispp

I've just released my c++ redis client on github. It's main feature right now is pipelining, I'll be adding more features soon, possibly sharding/consistent hashing next.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a C++ Redis client: [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus). It's based on *hiredis*, and written in C++11. It supports the following features:

- Most commands for Redis.
- Connection pool.
- Redis scripting.
- Thread safe unless otherwise stated.
- Redis publish/subscribe.
- Redis pipeline.
- Redis transaction.
- Redis Cluster.
- Redis Sentinel.
- Redis Stream.
- STL-like interface.
- Generic command interface.

It's very fast, and easy to use. If you have any problem with this client, feel free to [let me know](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/issues). If you like it, also feel free to [star it](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) :)

```
#include <sw/redis++/redis++.h>
using namespace sw::redis;

try {
    Redis redis("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379");

    redis.set("key", "val");
    auto val = redis.get("key");
    if (val) {
        // dereference val to get the value of string type.
        std::cout << *val << std::endl;
    }   // else key doesn't exist.

    redis.rpush("list", {"a", "b", "c"});
    std::vector<std::string> list;
    redis.lrange("list", 0, -1, std::back_inserter(list));

    // put a vector<string> to Redis list.
    redis.rpush("another-list", list.begin(), list.end());

    auto tx = redis.transaction();

    auto tx_replies = tx.incr("num0")
                        .incr("num1")
                        .mget({"num0", "num1"})
                        .exec();

    auto redis_cluster = RedisCluster("tcp://127.0.0.1:7000");

    // RedisCluster has similar interface as Redis.
    redis_cluster.set("key", "value");
    val = redis_cluster.get("key");
} catch (const Error &err) {
    // error handling.
}
```

Check the [doc](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) for details.

Answer (score 1):

*disclaimer: I'm the author of redis3m*

Another C++ client can be found here: https://github.com/luca3m/redis3m

It's a wrapper of hiredis, with nice C++ classes, an high availability connection pooling and a set of patterns already implemented and ready to use.